# How do you test a machine learning algorithm if the data-set is imbalanced?

Tags: machine-learning, imbalanced-data

I have a data-set with good and malicious files. Labelled as 0 and 1. In the data-set there are more malicious files - like 3000 vs 800 good files. Nevertheless I am getting good results with logistic regression, random forest and SVM. I have tweaked the parameters to be adjusted for imbalanced datasets. The recall is always above 0.90 and accuracy 0.86-0.9 The AUC score is always around 0.87 to 0.9 depending on the algorithm. Now my question is , in real life the files that will run through the algorithm will mostly be good (millions) and malicious ones will be a few thousand. The opposite way around than on my data-set. Should that be a problem for my testing?

[ROC curves plotted for all my algorithms - the performance on the test set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfK8k.png)

Comment: Are the results you report on a validation or test set (i.e. unseen during model fitting), without any artificial samples created?

Comment: A more realistic way to evaluate your model performance is to sample a subset of data following the distribution of true testing data. By doing so, you can have a more reliable performance estimate.